# aws sdk for .net ec2 "Unable to reach credentials server"

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I have installed the AWS SDK for .Net.

I need to write a program to change the permissions for a security group, and I found an example of how to do this in C# on http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/sdk-net/latest/aws-sdk-net-dg.pdf (page 39).

```
Dim ipPermission As New IpPermission()
            ipPermission.IpProtocol = "tcp"
            ipPermission.FromPort = 3389
            ipPermission.ToPort = 3389
            ipPermission.IpRanges = IPRange

            Dim ingressRequest As New AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest()
            ingressRequest.GroupId = "sg-xxxxxxxx"
            ingressRequest.IpPermissions.Add(ipPermission)


            Dim endpoint As RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
            config.RegionEndpoint = endpoint
                         Dim ec2Client As New AmazonEC2Client(credentials, config)
            Dim ingressResponse As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse) = ec2Client.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressAsync(ingressRequest)
```

However, when I try to run the code it comes up with the following exception:

```
Unable to reach credentials server
```

Is this a bug in the SDK, or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried everything that I can think of and nothing is helping, and I'm desperate for help!

Comment: I urgently need this to work and I just can't figure out what the problem is. Please can someone help me!

Comment: I am really quite desperate!!! Any suggestions?

Comment: Seeing this on 2021-04-28... cannot find a AWS dashboard showing they have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old but i had the same issue with my app trying to reach a S3 bucket with AWS SDK and I didn't want to use AWS secret/key.

This article can help connecting to S3 from an EC2 : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/?nc1=h_ls

If more debuging is needed, you can connect to your EC2 using Session Manager and try calling the metadata service wich gives SDK credentials : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Another great article about the metadata service : https://blog.gruntwork.io/authenticating-to-aws-with-instance-metadata-b6d812a86b40#:~:text=Part%20of%20the%20information%20available,attached%20to%20that%20EC2%20Instance.

Plus if your task is using Windows Server image, it may have trouble reaching the metadata service from docker inside EC2 instance, you may have to add this command to your entrypoint to make it available : `route add 169.254.169.254 $((Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop)`